# How to order by Vietnamese alphabet in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have database like below:

```
    WITH TB AS(
     SELECT 1 ID, N'Bấm kim' NAMES FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
     SELECT 2 ID, N'Quét keo, dán mylar da đệm mắt cáo' NAMES  FROM DUAL 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 3 ID, N'Đục lỗ, gắn, đóng nút da trên nắp' NAMES  FROM DUAL 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 4 ID, N'Ăn kem' NAMES  FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT * FROM TB ORDER BY NAMES ASC
```

How can I order by NAMES column with alphabet of VietNamese. like

A Ă Â, B, C, D, Đ... How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to set the session parameter `NLS_SORT`. Another way is to order by NLSSORT(..., ...) (see below).

**First method, altering `NLS_SORT` for the session:**

Compare:

```
alter session set nls_sort = German;

Session altered.

WITH TB AS(
  SELECT 1 ID, N'Bấm kim'                            NAMES FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2 ID, N'Quét keo, dán mylar da đệm mắt cáo' NAMES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 ID, N'Đục lỗ, gắn, đóng nút da trên nắp'  NAMES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 ID, N'Ăn kem'                             NAMES FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT * FROM TB ORDER BY NAMES ASC;

   ID NAMES                             
----- ----------------------------------
    1 Bấm kim                           
    3 Đục lỗ, gắn, đóng nút da trên nắp 
    4 Ăn kem                            
    2 Quét keo, dán mylar da đệm mắt cáo
```

vs.

```
alter session set nls_sort = Vietnamese;

Session altered.

WITH TB AS(
  SELECT 1 ID, N'Bấm kim'                            NAMES FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2 ID, N'Quét keo, dán mylar da đệm mắt cáo' NAMES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 ID, N'Đục lỗ, gắn, đóng nút da trên nắp'  NAMES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 ID, N'Ăn kem'                             NAMES FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT * FROM TB ORDER BY NAMES ASC;

   ID NAMES                             
----- ----------------------------------
    4 Ăn kem                            
    1 Bấm kim                           
    3 Đục lỗ, gắn, đóng nút da trên nắp 
    2 Quét keo, dán mylar da đệm mắt cáo
```

**Second method, using Vietnamese for just this query (see the ORDER BY clause!)**

```
WITH TB AS(
  SELECT 1 ID, N'Bấm kim'                            NAMES FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2 ID, N'Quét keo, dán mylar da đệm mắt cáo' NAMES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 ID, N'Đục lỗ, gắn, đóng nút da trên nắp'  NAMES FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 ID, N'Ăn kem'                             NAMES FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT * FROM TB ORDER BY NLSSORT(NAMES, 'nls_sort = Vietnamese') ASC;

   ID NAMES                             
----- ----------------------------------
    4 Ăn kem                            
    1 Bấm kim                           
    3 Đục lỗ, gắn, đóng nút da trên nắp 
    2 Quét keo, dán mylar da đệm mắt cáo
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the NLSSORT function
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions104.htm#SQLRF00678

```
   WITH TB AS(
     SELECT 1 ID, N'Bấm kim' NAMES FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
     SELECT 2 ID, N'Quét keo, dán mylar da đệm mắt cáo' NAMES  FROM DUAL 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 3 ID, N'Đục lỗ, gắn, đóng nút da trên nắp' NAMES  FROM DUAL 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 4 ID, N'Ăn kem' NAMES  FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT * FROM TB ORDER BY nlssort(NAMES,'NLS_SORT = VIETNAMESE') ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `ORDER BY` Vietnamese alphabet by `CASE` expression like this.

```
WITH TB AS(
    SELECT 1 ID, N'Bấm kim' NAMES FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
     SELECT 2 ID, N'Quét keo, dán mylar da đệm mắt cáo' NAMES  FROM DUAL 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 3 ID, N'Đục lỗ, gắn, đóng nút da trên nắp' NAMES  FROM DUAL 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 4 ID, N'Ăn kem' NAMES  FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT *
FROM TB 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN NAMES LIKE 'Â%' OR NAMES LIKE 'Ă%' OR NAMES LIKE 'A%' THEN 1
              WHEN NAMES LIKE 'B%' THEN 2
              WHEN NAMES LIKE 'C%' THEN 3
              WHEN NAMES LIKE 'D%' THEN 4
              WHEN NAMES LIKE 'Đ%' THEN 5
              .....etc
              END ASC
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f77bc/25)

Comment: Great! But... how will this work when the first letter is the same, and the sorting must then consider the **second** letter?